# List.remove() is behaving differently for negative values

Tags: java, exception

I have a requirement in our code, where we need to catch `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and move forward with other elements.

However, when i try to do that i am getting `ConcurrentModificationException`

Following code is something that i want but it is throwing `ConcurrentModificationException` exception at `line #1`

**Note that list.remove(1000) is not causing any issue  but list.remove(-1) does**

```
public class Test1 {
        public static void main(String[] argv) {
            test(new ArrayList<>());
        }

        public static void test(List<Integer> list) {
            list.add(42);
            Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator();

            try {
                list.remove(-1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

            try {
                if (it.next() != 42);//Line #1
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Can some one help me understand this behavior and how can I fix this problem ?

Comment: I don't think there is any way to achieve what you are expecting. You could try using a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` instead of `ArrayList` in your example but it will still iterate on the old list on successful removal (i.e. it wont iterate on the new removed item list) if that is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this problem is not to pass a negative index to `list.remove()`.

The reason this second exception occurs is that `remove` performs a partial range check, that only checks if the passed `index` is too large. It doesn't check if it's negative, since it relies on the access of the backing array to throw the exception in this case.

So, for negative index, the `modCount` of the `ArrayList` is incremented before the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown. As a result, trying to continue iterating over the list after catching this exception throws `ConcurrentModificationException`.

```
public E remove(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);

    modCount++;
    E oldValue = elementData(index); // ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown here

    int numMoved = size - index - 1;
    if (numMoved > 0)
        System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,
                         numMoved);
    elementData[--size] = null; // clear to let GC do its work

    return oldValue;
}
```

Note that `list.remove(1000)` will not cause this issue, since the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` will be thrown before `modCount` is incremented.

Of course, if the element removal was successful, you may still fail with `ConcurrentModificationException`, since the only way to safely remove elements from the `List` while iterating over it is to use the `Iterator`'s `remove()` method.

One more thing - I'm not sure if you intended to call `public E remove(int index)` or `public boolean remove(Object o)`. The former (which is the one that was chosen by the compiler) attempts to remove the element at the specified index, while the latter removes the specified element if found.

For a `List<Integer>`, passing an `int` to that method will attempt to remove by index even if you wanted to remove by element. If you wanted to remove by element, you should pass a reference type - `list.remove(Integer.valueOf(-1))`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are already getting an iterator from list and meanwhile removing items from the list directly hence the iterator cried.

Once you got to declare the iterator use only iterator to do the modifications.

So in the first try block remove using/ through iterator and not on list directly. Find the element and remove from iterator.

```
it.remove();
```

Comment: I was expecting like NoSuchElementException :(

Comment: @Suresh: java.util.Iterator has no remove(int i) only remove() method. So it.remove(-1); won't compile.

Comment: @riskop Yes Yes.